# Cannot connect to MySQL database with a user who has all privileges for it

Tags: mysql

Let me describe my problem:
I have a database that could be operated only by one user (except the admin). I've created this user by (`CREATE USER 'dbms'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`).Then I've created the database itself (`CREATE DATABASE dbms_db;`) and granted the user with all privileges (`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbms_db.* to 'dbms'@'localhost';`). Finally, I flushed the privileges(`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`). Even if I run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dbms'@'localhost';` the result is:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dbms@localhost                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dbms'@'localhost'                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbms_db`.* TO 'dbms'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I try to connect to the database with this user the access is denied.

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u dbms -D dbms_db -p 
> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'dbms'@'localhost' to database 'dbms_db'
```

Just to clarify, I can access the database if I'm using the root user. Also, I can connect to the MySQL client with `dbms` user if I'm not specifying the database with the `-D` flag.

Answer (score 0):

1.try to check the table user in the database mysql and make sure the acount has the logining right @localhost.the following is the image in my database;
[image]
2.if you are using a vitual machine in one computer,then you must using  exactly @ip rather than @localhost.